# Advice needed for a small web application's architecture/implementation

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications

I was asked to build a website where a company's employees (around 20) could login and fill in their working schedules for a present and past (if needed) month. Employees should ofcourse only be able to see their own schedules, but the manager should have the privilege to access every schedule.
I have little experience in web development therefore an advice is needed. I have already created a PHP/MySql login page. Now what? How do I go about it? 
Just some architectural or implementational(if you will) guidance would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have built applications similar to this in PHP / Mysql and can say that it's a good platform for it, although something like Rails might be quicker to use and require less micromanaging. As Wisdom says, use a framework to cut out some of the grunt work and ensure you're adhering to good security practices.

A few things come to mind that you'll need.

- Clarity about what your database structure will look like. Try to identify: a) all the pieces of information you'll need to store (A user's name? login info? "authority" level to see others' entries?), b) what tables they can go in. (Can "name" and "hours worked" go in the same table? If they are different levels of analysis, should they go in different tables? Are those two bits of information connected somehow? If so, how should I represent that connection?) Relational design is your friend, especially if you're building something that might get revised later. Take the time to understand what it's about.
- A page (view) for each different "type" of activity, would be a good place to start. So have a "Let me see my schedule" page, with links to a "Let me add a time entry" page and a "Let me edit that time entry" page. My experience is that, striving to keep your "view" pages' code as *small and easy-to-read* as possible, pushes you to better plan your code structure.
- ANY values that you insert into a query string, should be sanitized. So queries to search or select values should always have any PHP variables filtered through a "cleaning" structure:

  $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE identifier = %s",
      mysql_real_escape_string($id));

  Rather than:

  $query = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE identifier = ".$id

  because any text which a user types into a search or insert field online, if it ends up in your query, could be executed as part of the query. A hacker could then use this to make your other security features useless.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! That was all I ever needed. I Really appreciate your help.
Could you please tell me how many hours would it approximately take You to have that kind of system up and running?

Comment: Hmm, I still have trouble estimating hours for projects. It would probably take me 15-20 hours to build a basic bare-bones system for time tracking & auditing as you describe, and another 20 to add various bells & whistles that improve usability (different options for page views, Jquery-based calendars and date-pickers, for example). Given that you're on a steep learning curve, I would double that. Be sure to budget enough time that you're not rushing and cutting corners -- I imagine you want to invest in your learning, not just "get it done".

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to select a framework like cakephp or symfony this way you can avoid some mistakes. if you want to create by your own

first decide the database architecture that will fullfill your need.

than try to make crud functionality for each table as php object.

I think this can make you get going

Answer (score 0):

I was heavily involved in the design of our company's internal dashboard, where employees can log-in and view pertinent company metrics. We used [CodeIgniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) as our framework and it worked *really well*! It's a PHP framework that uses MySQL, which we already had both PHP and MySQL installed on our servers. There were already a few people in our company who had experience with it, as it has been around a few more years and is more established than the latest and greatest fad frameworks.  It has worked beautifully because of its [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) approach to development.  We have attached it to our home-cooked database using [Grocery CRUD](http://www.grocerycrud.com/). It has plug-ins that handle user authentication, sessions, and security. We have been extremely productive with it and I highly recommend.  Keep in mind, this framework is designed for developers that want to create something *very customizable*.  That being said, it provides basic things you need but lets you handle the higher-level stuff yourself.

You will need to design your database to meet your real-world constraints. 
With MySQL you can create a relational database that reflects users and their positions. We created an [E-R Diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) first to help our company's executives visualize the constraints and how we could model our business via the database, so that they could be involved in the discussion during the design phase.